# Бордер вокруг картинки

Tags: html, css

Как правильно сделать бордер при ховере, что бы она не двигалась?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

задать бордер при обычном состоянии в цвет фона, и при ховере в нужный цвет (в вашем случае  в зеленый).

```
img {border:1px solid #fff;}
img:hover {border:1px solid #000;}
```

Comment: Лучше не в цвет фона, а прозрачный тогда. 
border: 1px solid transparent

Comment: border-color: transparent - не поддерживает ИЕ6 - он создает черную границу. С учетом того, что не все отказались от ИЕ6 - надежнее ставить в цвет фона (если он однородный).

Answer (score 3):

```
img{
 padding:2px;
}
img:hover{
 padding:0;
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

Попробуйте так